# ruby on rails, how to using try() method in this case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails tag to call an attribute from an object like this

```
<%= item.product.name %>
```

but I got the error undefined method 'product' for nilClass. I've tried to use try() method like in the following code, it allows nill object from product,

```
<%= item.try(:[], 'product') %>,
```

but I don't know how to get name attribute from product now.

edited:
i try this code `item.try(:product).try(:[], :name)` the same code like mr @Andrey Daineko and mr @santhosh suggest,
this is the result if product not nill, its work
[image]

but it's still give this error if product is nill,

[image]

Comment: But `item` isn't a hash, is it?

Answer (score 4):

You call try on the return value of try

```
item.try(:product).try(:name)
```

or if product is a Hash,

```
item.try(:product).try(:[], :name)
```

Comment: i have edit my question with the result for your suggestion code, it's still give the same error if product nil..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, Access hash with try, which was OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

Use safe navigation (available from Ruby 2.3.0):

```
item&.product&.name 
# for Ruby < 2.3.0
item.try(:product).try(:name)
```

For hashes use [Hash#`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) (available from Ruby 2.3.0):

```
hash.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz) 
# for Ruby < 2.3.0
hash.fetch(:foo, {}).fetch(:bar, {}).fetch(:baz, {})
```

Comment: i've try this item.try(:product).try(:name), but that still give the same error undefined method 'product',

item&.product&.name  <- and it's give me a syntax error "syntax error, unexpected '.' ...;@output_buffer.append=( item&.product&.name );"

Comment: @AuliyaFadli then it means you do not have neither method `product` nor association  between `Item` and `Product` model. But this is another story, this answer is about how to use safe navigation (which you have initially asked about).

Comment: i have method product sure, it's just doesn't work if the product is null, if it isn't null it work..

Comment: @AuliyaFadli how do you have a method when it says you do not have it? show your method please

Comment: it's said undefined method if only the 'product' is nill... i've tried this 'item.product.name' when it is not nill, and it's work perfectly..

Comment: sorry, this is defined by the association in line_item model, 

` has_one :product, through: :variant`

Comment: @AuliyaFadli There is not way it will not work. `try` works on **anything** including `nil` and `false`

Comment: sure i know that's try() method work for nil, but i don't know why for this case, 

thanks  mr @Andrey Daineko,

i have edit the question with the print screen, please take a look..